# save mp3 data in file on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudioplayer

I'm developing an iPhone application and i need to download and **Save**  mp3 media on the iPhone and play it,
I fished the downloading work and i put the data in NSMutableData variable But **How can i save these data as mp3 file**

any advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**here is the correct soulution *appending up on @Diziet comment***

'//prepare data to save in file
NSData *fileData=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:(NSData *)receivedData];

```
NSString *mp3FileName = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFileName.mp3"];
//create the file
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:mp3FileName contents:receivedData attributes:nil];

//load the file for playing
NSString *FileNamePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"MyFileName.mp3"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appSettingsPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileNamePath];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:appSettingsPath ];
player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
player.delegate=self;
[player play];'
```

Comment: If an answer was helpful to you in finding the solution to the problem could you vote for it please?  Even if the given answer was not the final solution it is beneficial to do so for person who answered, and indeed to those who read the question later.  Also you may wish to edit your original question to include the follow up question you posted in the comments as it would further clarify your accepted answer to people who may read this later.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save it to your applications Documents directory with a .mp3 file extension you can use the following:

```
NSString *mp3FileName = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                              NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                              YES) lastObject]
                         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFileName.mp3"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:mp3FileName 
                                        contents:mp3Data 
                                      attributes:nil];
```

Where mp3Data is your NSMutableData.  I use code similar to the above for saving PDF documents, custom file formats, jpgs and all sorts.  I've not had cause to try mp3 yet but there's no reason why it shouldn't.

To read the file back into NSData to send to AVAudioPlayer:

```
NSString *mp3FileName = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                          NSUserDomainMask, 
                                                          YES) lastObject]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFileName.mp3"];
NSData *mp3Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mp3FileName];
avAudioPlayer.data = mp3Data;
```

Above para of code untested, never had cause to use sounds in my apps.

Comment: how can play this file after save it in this way?

Comment: I guess from the tag you are using AVAudioPlayer?  Which has a data property that is NSData?  I've never used it but if you just read in the file to NSData and bung that at AVAudioPlayer object no?

Comment: Guesswork, but I've tried to add a snippet to do what you want.  I mean it will populate the NSData object with the mp3 but I know nothing of avaudioplayer.